# Why double click on tabbaritem make the selected image back?

Tags: ios, custom-controls, uitabbar

In this [link](http://blog.theanalogguy.be/2011/09/14/custom-colored-uitabbar-icons-an-update/), the author provide a useful way to fulfill a custom tabbar. But facing a bug that when double click the tabbaritem, the gray image will come back, why?

http://blog.theanalogguy.be/2011/09/14/custom-colored-uitabbar-icons-an-update/

Comment: "Double Click" is a term for PC users. Why would you use it in an iOS app, let alone attached to a UITabBarButtonItem?

Comment: @stavash sorry for the confusing word. It means you click the tabbaritem you already choose.I just want to remove the highlight effect after the click.

Comment: Are you building for iOS 5 or are you building for earlier devices?

Comment: @JustinPaulson Yes I know there is an API in iOS5. But thank you for the reply.